# Advanced Options Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to make an Advanced Options Dialog for my application. I want it to look like the image below, to have a left panel and a right panel for particularly options in every category:
[image]

I would be grateful for (free) complete resources about this topic.

Comment: See Treeviews: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx and Panels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx and finally: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Are you asking for help laying out your form?

Comment: yeah, that's I want, and also programming to make the interface to work

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to help you answer specific questions or to help you solve problems that you can't solve yourself; it's not a place for you to get free programming labor where we just do your work for you?

Comment: no. that's not I mean, you don't work for me, I wanted to know if anybody does know a website to help me with this.

Comment: SO is not the place to go for product recommendations.  It is considered both too localized, subjective, spam encouraging, etc. to ask a question that is just looking for referrals.  SO is designed such that questions can actually be answered here, in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinForms this is easy enough:

- Create a MainForm class with a `TreeView` or `ListBox` on the left hand side, and a `Panel` on the right hand side. Be sure to set the `Anchor` properties of the controls accordingly.
- You might want to use the `Split` control to allow users to horizontally resize the the treeview, but in most cases this isn't necessary. If you do use a split then use the `Dock` property instead of `Anchor`.
- For each different right-hand-side panel create a `UserControl` subclass with the controls on. I recommend being MVC-ish in this respect: each control you create should have two methods: `ShowData(Data d)` and `UpdateData(Data d)` rather than having the control interact with your program's or data state directly.
- When the MainForm loads, create instance of each UserControl and add them to the `Panel`, but only make one of them visible at any given time.
- When a treeview node is selected you'd just set that control's `.Visible = true` and everything else to `false`.

But this is very simple, I don't know why you'd need advice for this.

Comment: Don't tell people your age on the Internet when you use your real-name...

Comment: I deleted the comment. Thanks for tip!

Comment: this option becomes bad when you have many controls. if you change the property of a control in the form with say 300 controls, in some cases, it would take 10 - 20 seconds to effect

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Form Project.  I can make the form project into a dll that I can then use in other projects

1) Left side a Tree view

2) MyOK, CANCEL, APPLY are control buttons

I wil have multiple forms so I can put all of them into a single project.